# Call sheet "1" to match the value and put into each array sheet, then add Formula to end of F8 offset 1

Tags: vba, for-loop

when i run it the error said object required and i dont know why. all i most want is put the for Formula to the row which is end of the "F" Column End(xlDown) and sum it all in the below cell.

[image: img1 image] [image: img2 image]

```
ttlerrrorcount = "0"
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1")
WshtNames = Array("32132121", "32131221", "31231", "32132123121", "321313213")

For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)

        For b = 8 To .Cells(8, "D").End(xlDown).Row
            ttl = 0
            ttlerror = ""
            vals = Split(.Cells(b, "D").Value2, Chr(44))
            For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                pc = Application.Match(vals(a), sh.Columns(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(pc) Then
                    ttl = ttl + sh.Cells(pc, "B").Value2
                ElseIf IsError(pc) Then
                    ttlerror = "Need follow-up"
                    ttlerrrorcount = ttlerrrorcount + 1
                End If
            Next a
            .Cells(b, "F") = ttl
            .Cells(b, "G") = ttlerror
        Next b

        'Total count of each sheet
        k = .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Row
        WshtNameCrnt.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(F8:F" & k & ")"

        With ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        'Total count of each sheet

    End With
Next WshtNameCrnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WshtNameCrnt.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

should be

```
.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

`WshtNameCrnt` is not a worksheet

Try something like:

```
k = .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Row

'make sure not at bottom of sheet
If k < .Rows.Count Then
    With .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        .Formula = "=sum(F8:F" & k & ")"
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End With
Else
    'if at bottom of the sheet do something else...
End With
```

Comment: error this time runtime 1004 Select method of range class failed.
.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: If your `End(xlDown)` takes you to the bottom of the sheet then you can't offset one more row down from there.  It's typically safer to start at the bottom of the sheet and use `End(xlUp)`

Comment: can not, since there another table below the table starting from F8.

Comment: In that case you'll need to add some checks around where your xlDown ends up before you try to offset from there.

Comment: Can you help with that, i have no clue